# Why can we not update the UI widgets outside of the UI thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, thread-safety, qthread

When using a UI based Framework such as Qt,Gtk, IOS programming, you cannot update UI components outside of the UI Thread. An example would be if I had a progress bar and wanted to periodically increment the value from 0 -> 100 outside of the UI Thread, it would crash.

However, I have not found a strong explanation as to why and what is happening under the hood to create this restriction. Could anyone explain why we cannot? Are we not just passing an object along and changing it's attributes, why would that cause a problem?

Comment: you can send progress value to main thread using queue and main thread can use timer to periodically get value from queue and update progressbar in main thread.

Comment: https://flylib.com/books/en/2.558.1/why_are_guis_single_threaded_.html